# split string and insert trigger phpMyAdmin

Tags: mysql, database, triggers, phpmyadmin

I want to get the name in test table and split it form "to" word & insert that splitted string in abc table.
the trigger fired,but when insert data into test it generate 
 "#1172 - Result consisted of more than one row" error in phpMyAdmin.
please help me with this.

```
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS `split_after_insert`;
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` 
TRIGGER `split_after_insert` AFTER INSERT ON `test` 
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
     DECLARE vName varchar(50);

     -- Find name of person performing the INSERT into table

    SELECT SUBSTR(name,(POSITION("to" IN name)+4),20) FROM test INTO vName;

    -- Insert record into abc table

   INSERT INTO abc(a) VALUES (vName);

END
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS `j`;
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` 
TRIGGER `j` AFTER INSERT ON `test` 
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN

   DECLARE vName varchar(100);
   DECLARE vtemp varchar(100);

   select new.name into vtemp;

   -- Find name of person performing the INSERT into table
   SELECT SUBSTR(vtemp,(POSITION("to" IN vtemp)+3),20)  INTO vName;

   -- Insert record into abc table
   INSERT INTO `abc`(`a`) VALUES (vName );

END
```